# How to change the sample rate of audio for all video files in a directory?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, video

I performed screen records using wf-recorder and I realized that it was hardcoded to encode at 44.1 kHz, but Pipewire defaults to 48 kHz. So it turned out the audio would be perfectly in sync if I slowed the audio stream to about 0.95x. The value isn't exactly consistent, but is around the same number.

In a video editor, the audio stream shows to cut off a few seconds before the end of the video, so basically I should stretch the audio until the ending matches the ending of the video. Theoretically adjusting the sample rate should be the easiest solution.

How do I do that? I wouldn't need to re-encode video, or even stretch the audio, only change the audio sample rate.

I would guess it will be something like `for i in *.mp4; do ffmpeg -i "$i" -c:v copy -c:a copy -ar 44100 "fixed/$i"; done`?

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** I realized `-ar 44100` would resample the audio, but I only wanted to re-encode the raw audio data. For that I had to use `-af 'asetrate=44100'` instead. I've updated the answer to that.

But ultimately I realized that the audio no longer matches up smoothly to a consistent value, and I'll have to adjust the tempo individually for each file using a video editor.

---

What I figured out was almost close to the answer. I had to omit copying the audio stream, because I had to re-encode to change the sample rate.

For BASH shell:

`for i in *.mp4; do ffmpeg -i "$i" -c:v copy -af 'asetrate=44100' "fixed/$i"; done`

For Fish shell:

`for i in *.mp4; ffmpeg -i "$i" -c:v copy -af 'asetrate=44100' "fixed/$i"; end`